# Number of sender threads in Kafka C API client

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using librdkafka-0.11.5 for C on Linux.
My C/C++ applications just send Kafka data to a web server which is driving Kafka consumer with ElasticSearch.
Looks like on the producer side Kafka adds 8 (eight) internal threads per Unix process. 
It causes a problem for us because we have a hard limit on number of thread per Linux box.

Does any body know why there are 8 threads added? Can it be because my Linux box has 4 CPUs and the thread pool is pre-created with two threads per CPU (just speculating)?
I use one topic and six partitions. The broker string has three brokers.

Is there any way to decrease number of those added threads?

Regards,
Nick

Answer (score 3):

The current librdkafka design creates one internal thread per broker in the cluster.

See the [FAQ](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/FAQ#number-of-internal-threads) for more information.

We're looking into changing this to IO threads, or on-demand broker threads, but that will not happen until 2019.

Comment: Thanks Edenhill! Does number of topic partitions matter to the thread count?
I decreased number of brokers to just one and this resulted in number threads down to 6. Trying to understand where those 6 are coming from...

Comment: Partition count does not matter.

Comment: The FAQ explains the number of threads created: 1 + N, where N is the number of brokers known to the client, through bootpstrap.servers and cluster metadata. A broker does not have to be up to have thread associated with it.